# Django : access data from serializer after saving it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, sendmail, serialization

I want to make an API to allow client to order online.
When the order is validated, I want to send an email to the client to confirm his order.
For that, I need the data that I just created (the order id, the delivery day and the delivery place).
This is my code : **models.py :**

```
class memberArea(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone = models.TextField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    deliveryAddress = models.TextField()
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    forget = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(memberArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    orderDay = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deliveryDay = models.DateField()
    deliveryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default="En attente")
    price = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    response = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class orderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    byProduct = models.ForeignKey(byProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**serializer.py :**

```
class orderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = orderDetail
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('order',)

class MakeOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    orderDetail = orderDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = order
        fields = ['user', 'comment', 'deliveryAddress', 'deliveryDay', 'orderDetail']

    def create(self, validated_data):
            order_detail_data = validated_data.pop('orderDetail')
            new_order = order.objects.create(**validated_data)
            new_order.save()
            for product in order_detail_data:
                order_detail = orderDetail.objects.create(order=new_order, **product)
            return new_order
```

**views.py :**

```
#Make an order
@api_view(['POST'])
def order(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MakeOrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data['response'] = "Your order went well"
            delivery_date = serializer.data['deliveryDay']
            delivery_place = serializer.data['deliveryAddress']
            order_id = serializer.data['id']
            message = "Thanks for your older.<br/>You will receive your order the <strong>{}</strong><br/>Delivery Place : <strong>{}/strong>.<br/>Order ID: <strong>{}</strong>.<br/>".format('delivery_day', 'delivery_address', 'order_id')
            send_mail(
                "Validation of your order !",
                message,
                "myaddress@gmail.com",
                ["useraddress@gmail.com"],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            return Response(data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

When I try to use my variables and run my code, this is what I get : `` Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `orderDetail` on serializer `MakeOrderSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `order` instance. Original exception text was: 'order' object has no attribute 'orderDetail'. ``
Thanks by advance for helping me.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you could give your questions a brief title. eg for this one it could be `access data from serializer after saving it`. It would be helpful for others too, who are having similar kind of issues. And if nothing clicks on how you should name  your title start from the `errors` you are getting.

Comment: Yes sorry I have trouble finding good titles for my questions ...

Comment: You have this tagged as sendmail. Are you actually using the sendmail program?

Comment: Yes I use the sendmail program

Answer (score 1):

To access data from `serializer` you can use `serializer.data['deliveryDate']`. Similarly you can access `serializer.data['orderDetail']` it will return a `list`, then you can iterate over it to access your other data.

Comment: Are you able to get any of the data from `serializer`? is `deliveryDate` accessible?

Comment: No, none of my variables are accessible

Comment: try to print `serializer.data` and check if you are getting the data.

Comment: When I do `print(serializer.data)` nothing happend

Comment: you need to ensure everything before that is running correctly. Try to print `serializer` just to check if data is there or not, also check for any `seriaizer` related issues.

Comment: With Django Rest Framework the result of a print is visible in the console that's it ?

Comment: Because whatever what I print I can't see any difference

Comment: Are you using `gunicorn`? or running web server with `python manage.py runserver` on development machine? In the latter case it should be visible in the terminal.

Comment: I use the command `python manage.py runserver`, but I don't see anything changing when I do a print, even if I `print('test')`

Comment: `if serializer.is_valid():` print('working') `else:` print(serializer.errors); Have this `else` statement whenever you work with serializer it will easier to debug.

Comment: Do I have to stop the server to see my print or should it appear automatically ?

Comment: Okay I find how it works, but when I try to `print(serializer.data)`, i get this error : `AssertionError: You cannot call '.save()' after accessing 'serializer.data'.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead.`

Comment: When I print serializer, that's what I get : `MakeOrderSerializer(data={'user': 8, 'deliveryDay': '2020-06-30', 'deliveryAddress': 'Place des Fêtes', 'comment': '', 'orderDetail': [{'product': 3, 'byProduct': 2, 'quantity': 80}, {'product': 1, 'byProduct': 3, 'quantity': 7}]}):`

Comment: so i guess now you can access `serializer.data`.

Comment: No, when I try to print serializer.data I get the same error (```Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `orderDetail` on serializer `MakeOrderSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `order` instance.
Original exception text was: 'order' object has no attribute 'orderDetail'.```)

Comment: I think it's because `orderDetail` is a list into a dictionary

Comment: yes it will be a `list` but you should be able to get it and print it in console. If any of the value is accessible such as `deliveryAddress` it means it working, rest based on your use case things might differ and whats where you have to debug and try out different things.